# Update multiple rows with values of from a specific row based on same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to optimize my query to use CTE and some windows functions for better improvement. I am updating existing rows with specified data from other row but they have the same ID number. The code is for MS SQL.

LinkTable:

```
  ID   |     TYPE  |  value1 |  Value2 |  Value3 
  -----------------------------------------------
  234  |     MAT   |    a    |     b   |    c
  234  |     PMS   |    null |    null | null
  234  |     AMN   |    null |    null | null
  45   |     MAT   |    x    |      m  |   n
  45   |     LKM   |    null |    null | null
  45   |     DFG   |    null |    null | null
  3    |     MAT   |    k    |      s  |  q
  3    |     LKM   |    null |    null | null
```

The result should be:

```
 ID   |     TYPE  |  value1 |  Value2 |  Value3 
 -----------------------------------------------
 234  |     MAT   |    a    |     b   |    c
 234  |     PMS   |    a    |     b   |    c
 234  |     AMN   |    a    |     b   |    c
 45   |     MAT   |    x    |      m  |   n
 45   |     LKM   |    x    |      m  |   n
 45   |     DFG   |    x    |      m  |   n
 3    |     MAT   |    k    |      s  |  q
 3    |     LKM   |    k    |      s  |  q
```

I used this code:

```
UPDATE m 
SET     m.[value1] = l.[value1]
    ,   m.[value2] = l.[value2]
    ,   m.[value2] = l.[value3]
FROM #LinkTable  m
    INNER JOIN #LinkTable  l on l.[ID] = m.[ID]
WHERE l.[type] = 'MAT'
```

It updates also the main row from which i take the values.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically fine, but I would add some filters:

```
UPDATE m 
    SET m.[value1] = l.[value1],
        m.[value2] = l.[value2],
        m.[value3] = l.[value3]
FROM #LinkTable m JOIN
     #LinkTable l 
     ON l.[ID] = m.[ID]
WHERE l.[type] = 'MAT' AND
      m.type <> 'MAT';
```

Note:  You also have an error in the `SET` clause.  The column `value2` is set twice.

Comment: Can you please provide another method with CTE or windows Function @GordonLinoff ?

Comment: @Serii . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask as a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions like this:

```sql
UPDATE m 
SET     m.[value1] = m.MATvalue1
    ,   m.[value2] = m.MATvalue2
    ,   m.[value3] = m.MATvalue3
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        MATvalue1 = MIN(CASE WHEN m.[type] = 'MAT' THEN l.value1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID),
        MATvalue2 = MIN(CASE WHEN m.[type] = 'MAT' THEN l.value2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID),
        MATvalue3 = MIN(CASE WHEN m.[type] = 'MAT' THEN l.value3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID)
    FROM #LinkTable  m
) m
WHERE m.[type] <> 'MAT';
```

Note that this may not necessarily be more performant than Gordon's answer

Comment: @chalieface , it updates all the rows including those which have type ='MAT'. Could you review your code?